# Thread Safety C# List<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know of and have used the `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>` for building thread safe code in the past. I have some legacy code that I'm trying to thread to increase performance however there is a non static List object that is being written with different sources of data.  All of the writing is being done prior to any reading of the list and my initial tests show that multiple threads appear to write to the object without any issues.

[Sample Windows App](https://pastebin.com/nn5TbcNQ)

Does a non static C# List object have thread safety for writing across multiple threads prior to reading?  How can this be tested?

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorkerA, backgroundWorkerB;
System.Threading.ManualResetEvent manualReset;
List<string> _shardList = new List<string>(0);

public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    manualReset = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
    backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorkerA.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorkerA.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerA_DoWork;

    backgroundWorkerB = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorkerB.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorkerB.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerB_DoWork;

    this.HandleCreated += UserControl1_HandleCreated;
}

private void UserControl1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorkerA.RunWorkerAsync(_shardList);
    backgroundWorkerB.RunWorkerAsync(_shardList);
    manualReset.Set();
}

private void BackgroundWorkerB_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> _shardList = (List<string>)e.Argument;
    manualReset.WaitOne();
    int _i = 0;
    while(!this.backgroundWorkerB.CancellationPending)
    {
        _shardList.Add("b" + _i++.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("b is running");
    }

    thread2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { thread2.Text = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, _shardList.ToArray()); }));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorkerA.CancelAsync();
    backgroundWorkerB.CancelAsync();
}

private void BackgroundWorkerA_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> _shardList = (List<string>)e.Argument;
    manualReset.WaitOne();
    int _i = 0;
    while (!this.backgroundWorkerA.CancellationPending)
    {
        _shardList.Add("a" + _i++.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("a is running");
    }

    thread1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { thread1.Text = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, _shardList.ToArray()); }));
}
```

Comment: What did you see in the documentation for `List` as to its thread safety, and how did that fail to answer your question?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#thread-safety

Comment: The documentation only mentions writing is not thread safe but doesn't provide details around when that would be the case.  A specific example on how reading and writing to a list is not thread safe and other questions on SO have explained that multiple threads can enumerate through a list as long as no writes are happening.  Nothing I've found so far has addressed multiple writers being thread or not thread safe.  With the simple code I've written to test it I would have expected the modifications to the the shared list in the background workers to have caused some data to be lost.

Comment: @DStanley That is the MS document that I'm referring to that provides details on when reads and writes by different threads would cause an enumerator issue.

Comment: If you want performance, you can start by replacing the `ConcurrentBag` with a `ConcurrentQueue`. `ConcurrentBag` is efficient **only** in the case where a thread is likely to consume the elements that it has enqueued. In all the other cases, it is very slow and puts a huge pressure on the GC

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple things that make concurrent writes to a `List<T>` unsafe.

First let's have a look at the code of the `Add` method:

```
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}
```

- The first issue is `EnsureCapacity`. If the list's inner array isn't big enough to receive the new element, it will create a new, bigger array, and copy the elements from the old one to the new one. If a thread writes in the old list after the copy but before the swap, the element will be lost
- The second issue is the non-atomic increment of `size`. If two threads try to write at the same time, they may write at the same index in the array, thus losing one item

Those race conditions are not very likely, but they'll eventually happen if you keep writing in the same list from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify a list, it has to modify the backing array. If one operation is making a change to the backing array at the same time as another, this can put the list into a broken state. You won't see this often unless you're doing very high frequency concurrent operations, but it's a lot better to use a concurrent collection then to discover the issue in production a few weeks or months later.

The following code just executes 1000000 writes in a row simultaneously on each core. On a multi-core machine, this will almost certainly throw an exception because the underlying array gets modified when another concurrent call is not expecting it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var list = new List<string>();

  void mutateList()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
      list.Add("foo");
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
  {
    new Thread(mutateList).Start();
  }


  Thread.Sleep(-1);
}
```